# Why does having a literal space between regex tokens lead to different matchdata objects?

Tags: ruby, regex

For example, consider the following expressions:

```
no_space = "This is a test".match(/(\w+)(\w+)/) 
with_space = "This is a test".match(/(\w+) (\w+)/)
```

The expression `no_space` is now the matchdata object `#<MatchData "This" 1:"Thi" 2:"s">`, while `with_space` is `#<MatchData "This is" 1:"This" 2:"is">`. What is going on here? It seems to me like the literal space between tokens indicates to ruby that it should match multiple words if possible, while not having a space causes the match to be limited to one word. Any explanation or clarification on the subject would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` doesn't match space, and `+` is greedy unless you follow it by `?`, so Ruby tries to match as many `\w` as possible, as long as the rest of the express also matches, effectively consuming `Thi` in the first capture, and `s` in the second.

When you add a space, Ruby matches as many `\w` until a space character, and then as many `\w`, therefore matching `This` and `is`.

Please let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: I didn't realize the space between the tokens was interpreted as looking for an actual space in the expression. Your answer helped! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the regular expression `/(\w+)(\w+)/`, the only characters that can be matched are word characters (letters, digits, and underscores).  A regular expression will only ever match consecutive characters in a string, so unless you include something in the regular expression to match the spaces between words the regex can't match more than a single word.

Comment: ... and because it is a greedy match it ends up in 'Thi' and 's'

Comment: The question seemed to be more about the one word vs two word matching, rather than the contents of the groups.